# Cordova 3.0 ios geolocation how to stop alert per screen

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, geolocation

I've been looking around for a while now and can't find a solution. I currently have a cordova project that uses the HTML5 geolocation capabilities. The thing is it asks every time page would like use your current location.

I have included the CDVLocation plugin but what still happens, it asks once per page and then if you quit the app it will ask again for each page.

The popup also contains an ugly message which contains the path to the html page in the app would like to use your location. Is there a way to make this process native so you only ever get asked once to approve and the popup isn't so cryptic to users.

I have tried a few things. Making sure I make the call after the device is ready and also included the InAppBrowser/CDVLocation plugin. But it doesn't seem to fix it.

If anyone has any ideas it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned you added the CDVLocation plugin, do you mean you did this at the command line:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.geolocation
```

I made the same mistake myself (forgetting to add the plugin) and since geolocation is built in, it "worked", but I got multiple prompts. I blogged about it here (http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2013/11/2/Seeing-two-geolocation-prompts-in-a-PhoneGapCordova-application).

Comment: Hmmm, I manually added it because I messed up my project. Maybe I have missed something. I think it is working though because it doesn't come up with the double popup. Ill just create a project and try adding it with the command line. Hopefully you're right. Thanks

Comment: I just setup a demo project and it seems to work fine thanks heaps for your help